# installing CoreOS using usb device and CoreOS ISO

Tags: disk-space-utilization, image, partition, coreos

I have some doubts about installing CoreOS using the image [ISO](https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/platforms/iso/).

I follow the steps in CoreOS docs, in the [Install](https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/bare-metal/booting-with-pxe/) section:

```
cfdisk -z /dev/sda
touch "/usr.squashfs (deleted)"     # work around a bug in mkfs.btrfs 3.12
mkfs.btrfs -L ROOT /dev/sda1
```

And then when I run the install script:

```
./coreos-install -d /dev/sda -c cloud-config.yml
```

I get the error about not enought space.

The [install script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/init/master/bin/coreos-install) of the CoreOS site posted in GitHub doesn't work for me because it tell me that there isn't enought space on device.

Then I have some doubts about it:

1. The hard disk has 250 Gb of memory.
2. The usb has almost 8 Gb of memory.

Why this error?

Comment: Can you please post the exact error you are getting ? I'm telling that because I had a similar problem installing Core OS on a virtual machine and it turned out I was assigning not enough RAM to the machine. I know, RAM seems unrelated to the disk space, but maybe it is downloading the ISO to a RAM disk.